# unique_ptr without move, why is this working?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

During a code review I found that a C++ function expecting a unique_ptr gets passed the uniqe_ptr by std::move but neither does the function move the unique_ptr as return value nor assigns the caller the return unique_ptr back to it's unique_ptr, so I'd expect this would crash.

Example:

```
   std::unique_ptr<X> fun(std::unique_ptr<X> p) {
     // Do something with the unique_ptr p
     return p;
   }
```

At some other place, I found the following calls:

```
void someFunction() {
  auto p = std::make_unique<X>();
  //...
  fun(std::move(p));
  // Do something else
  fun(std::move(p));
  //...
}
```

So I'm wondering whether this code is OK or if it is just luck that it executes.

*[EDIT]: Completed the example*

Comment: Are you saying that `p` is moved-from *twice*?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Yes it's actually moved twice (I extended the example to be more clear)

Comment: Doing `std::move(p)` twice is not a problem. The first `std::move` will set the `unique_ptr` to `nullptr` so the second `fun(std::move(p))` should pass`nullptr` to your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this fragment:

```
fun(std::move(p));
fun(std::move(p));
```

`p` is moved-from, which leaves it null.  So the second time you call `fun()`, it receives a null pointer.   Which is fine, so long as it does not dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the intent was to call `fun` like this:

```
p = fun(std::move(p));
p = fun(std::move(p));
```

In which case ownership of `p` would be passed back-and-forth to and from the function. I would have preferred to make `fun` a void function and pass `p` in by reference or even as a raw `X*` type.